# Exclusive behavior for Checkboxs in Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a angular project in which user is able to see news from different news sources. I have created a navigation pane which shows all the news sources fetched with checkbox.[Navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oEBm.png).

Behavior i am trying to achieve is like this - [Behavior i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgU8O.png)

**Navigation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NewsfetchserviceService } from '../newsfetchservice.service';
import { NewsData } from '../NewsData';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit{

  sourcesList : NewsData[] = [];
  selectAllFilter = true;
  selectSingleFilter = true;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showAllSources();
  }

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,private newsfetch: NewsfetchserviceService) {}

  showAllSources():void {
    this.sourcesList = this.newsfetch.allNews;
    /* this.newsfetch.getNews().subscribe(news => this.news = news); */
  }

  updateNewsList(source : NewsData):void{
    this.newsfetch.updateNewsBlock(source);
    this.selectAllFilter = false;
    this.checkboxBehaviour(2);
  }

  updateAllNewsList(source : NewsData[]):void{
    this.newsfetch.updateAllNewsBlock(source);
    this.checkboxBehaviour(1);
  }

  checkboxBehaviour(input : number):void{
    if(this.selectSingleFilter == false && this.selectAllFilter == false && input == 1)
    {
      this.selectSingleFilter = true;
      this.selectAllFilter = true;
    }else{
      this.selectSingleFilter = false;
      this.selectAllFilter = false;
    }

    if(input == 2)
    {
      this.selectSingleFilter = false;
      this.selectAllFilter = false;
    }
     
    
  }
}
```

**Navigation.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            All Sources
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="selectAllFilter" (change)="updateAllNewsList(sourcesList)">Select All</mat-checkbox>
        <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let source of sourcesList">
            <!-- <a mat-list-item (click)="updateNewsList(source)">{{source.name}}</a> -->
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="selectSingleFilter" (change)="updateNewsList(source)">{{source.name}}</mat-checkbox>
           <!--  <a mat-list-item >Hibernate</a> -->
            <!-- <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">Struts</a> -->
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>HUKUM</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <app-newsblock></app-newsblock>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I am using Angular Material `<mat-checkbox>` for checkbox. I am using its `[checked]` property tied to variable to update their checked status on action. I am using two bool variables `selectAllFilter` for select All checkbox and `selectSingleFilter` for all other sources. I am failing to handle second case as i have only variable used for multiple source's checkbox. I am thinking having a unique variable tied to `[checked]` for each source checkbox will make this problem easy to tackle but sources list size can dynamically changed and will cause issues if i hardcode and create so many variables.

Comment: is there a reference for checked in the object which is you display? for example { name: 'Primary', checked: false}

Comment: do you mean like this `<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectAllFilter"`? Here `selectAllFilter` is a boolean value

Comment: I only see the desired behavior, didn't check your code. The second and fourth cases are pretty much similar so you need to distinguish them. My idea is add one flag variable such as `isFirstLoad`, with isFirstLoad = true, you know you're handling the second case. Whenever user click a checkbox, you make that isFirstLoad = false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.